# How can I debug a stored procedure running from a Service Broker queue in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, debugging, service-broker

I have a table with a complex trigger that eventually calls the Service Broker to run a stored procedure with a parameter that is a table (custom type).

I can "step into" the INSERT and the trigger, but I can't step into the service broker stored procedure, as it runs async as far as I understand.

Is there any way to tap into the stored procedure that the Service Broker runs and debug it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To debug it (using the management studio debugger) you could alter the queue to set activation off.

```
ALTER QUEUE queue_name 
WITH ACTIVATION (STATUS = OFF);
```

run the insert statement then run & debug the activation procedure manually just like you would with any stored procedure. 
This way there will be something in the queue while you debug. 
Then when finished use `STATUS = ON` to restore activation.

Comment: This does not work if the error only occurs when service broker runs it.  I am having an issue right now where running the proc by itself works but fails when SB runs it.  Seems like SB is killing the connection during a web request.

Comment: Good point but this should be a separate question. I would check the user permissions first, there is an EXECUTE AS clause for SB activation. Have fun :)

Comment: Thanks, my issue turned out to be caused by max text size being set at 4K.  I solved it with set sextsize -1.  Took me 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but maybe someone else has this problem.

You can use SQL Profiler to catch the line number and proc where an error is happening.  If you use Print statements then they will show up in the profiler.